# Automatically create a JIRA ticket from a Template

Tags: jira, confluence

I need to create a form/template that has all the required fields and that will auto generate a Jira ticket. Is it possible to do something like this in Jira/Confluence?

Answer (score 1):

I think your question would be better suited at an atlassian community forum rather than stackoverflow, as similar questions have been asked over there e.g. [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Can-i-create-a-jira-issue-from-within-Confluence/qaq-p/21619) and [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Create-a-jira-issue-from-Confuence-with-custom-form/qaq-p/517952).

However, to answer your question, I did a quick search and I think this plugin might be your answer if you have a confluence server instance: [Issue Forms for Confluence](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.aevolu.j.in.c/server/overview)